# Making element draggable after prepend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a function that shows a notification and I want that notification to be draggable when it is added to the page.

I currently have a main parent div to hold all the notification divs called `notification_holder`

Full thing:

```
<div class="notification_holder">
    <div class="container"><br><br><br>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="notification_area">
            <!-- Notificiations will automatically be added here. -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SendNotification function:

```
function showNotification_event(notificationTitle, notificationContent) {
    var notificationArea = $('#notification_area');

    var notificationHtml = '<div id="draggable" class="panel panel-pink">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-heading">';
    notificationHtml += notificationTitle;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-body">';
    notificationHtml += notificationContent;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';

    $("#notification_area").prepend(notificationHtml);

}
```

and I declare this at the start of the .js file:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

I do have all the files, before people say that:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

The problem is, it just isn't draggable, can anyone help with this?

Comment: I'm guessing `#draggable` doesn't exist yet when you apply `.draggable()` on it? After prepending you should run `$('#draggable').draggable()`.

Comment: You can initialize as the draggable before you prepend or after. Since you're trying to call it at the beginning of your JS file, the element does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind events to elements after they are created.

This may help you:

```js
function showNotification_event(notificationTitle, notificationContent) {
    var notificationArea = $('#notification_area');
    debugger;
    var notificationHtml = '<div id="draggable" class="panel panel-pink">';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-heading">';
    notificationHtml += notificationTitle;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '<div class="panel-body">';
    notificationHtml += notificationContent;
    notificationHtml += '</div>';
    notificationHtml += '</div>';

    notificationArea.prepend(notificationHtml);
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="notification_holder">
    <div class="container"><br><br><br>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="notification_area">
            <!-- Notificiations will automatically be added here. -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="click" onclick="showNotification_event('test title', 'test content')">button</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```